# How to Create Tabgroup on smartface app studio

Tags: smartface.io

I have tried to create a tab-view or tab-group like control on smartface.io but I can't find any solution on the website.

Please any one have idea on how to create tab group. I can't find any tab-view on their the view pallet of IDE. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use textbuttons, place them at the top of the page, use as many as you need. And place container objects under these buttons. When you press a button, make the related container's visibility true and other's false. For example, when pressed button1, let

```
cont1.visible = true;
cont2.visible = false;
cont3.visible = false;
```

and so on.

Also you should check Smartface in Action project. You can find project in Welcome page, for example in pgListView.